# Xcode IOS One View Controller on 2 views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to have one view controller save data or control two views?

Say like a 2 page questionnaire. Instead of have a view controller for each page can one view controller save data from both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, yes, but only one view can be considered the view controller's actual view (the property)

This is important because sublassed view controller methods like

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
-(void)viewWillAppear
```

etc

will only call for the actual view of the view controller.

Comment: Oh I see. i realized that when I tried to update a variable in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Thanks for this again. Really helped me on the right path.

Comment: you bet! happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer **YES** you can have one view controller and control multiple views on that view controller.

Comment: I have it setup, but my problem is it still acts as a separate controller. My variables reset when the second page is loaded.

Comment: That is a different question. You need to be very clear in your questions and share code of the problem detailing what exact the problem is. As it stands this answers your question.

Comment: There isnt much code in a storyboard. Having one view controller on 2 views when I do an addition the variable resets when page 2 loads.

It is quite obvious I do not understand  how to go about using 1 view controller on 2 views

Comment: That just adds to the information that you need to share in your question. Please share code and all relevant information we aren't mind readers you need to share as much as possible.

Comment: I explained in my comment above what I am trying to do and what happens.

Comment: A comment isn't your question and you haven't shared anything

Comment: I added an answer. Figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

I realized that I have to still treat the second page differently even though it uses the same view controller.

I solved my problem by

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    Test *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.testInt = 2;

}
```